# No route matches [DELETE] "/events"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I searched and tried other things, but I don't get it. When I'm on the event page, you can click "Edit" or "Delete". Only if you are the user that created it.

Problem: I click "Delete". I get 3 times a confirm: "Are you sure?" after I clicked them all "ok" it says "No route matches [DELETE] "/events"

These are the buttons "Edit" and "Delete". I work with Devise for the user system:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <% if current_user.id == @event.user.id && user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", events_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I got an controller named "events_controller". I followed an tutorial and used the same things. I used the CRUD system. Create Read Update Delete:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index #index pagina
  @event = Event.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

def new
@event = current_user.events.build
end

#CRUD actions

def create
 @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
  if @event.save
    redirect_to @event, notice: "Event created."
  else
   render 'new'
 end
end

def edit
end

def update #event updaten
 if @event.update(event_params)
   redirect_to @event, notice: "Event updated."
 else
   render 'edit'
 end
end

def destroy
  @event.destroy
  redirect_to events_path
end

private
 def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :image)
 end

 def find_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

These are my routes:
https://gyazo.com/57c5b0da9a82dbcc2744e0f8262d0f8d

Comment: `events_path` here you're passing a path. you should pass an object you want to delete instead. e.g `user or @user`

Comment: @Marv-C I think I understand but what should a write then? Because I say `@event.destroy` and `redirect_to events_path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event_path` (NOT `events_path`) needs to know the ID of the event, so you need to pass the event to it.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", event_path(@event), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

`events_path` is only for collection methods, not for methods that act on a single event.  And there's no `events_path` DELETE in your routes (and you don't need it)

Comment: hi! Now it says `No route matches [DELETE] "/events.6"`

Comment: What is the output of rake routes when you run it in your console?

Comment: Did you change it from `events_path` to `event_path` ?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thanks! It worked! Now, I only need to make a page "my events" to see the events that you created :-) thanks a lot mate!

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I still got the message "Are you sure?" 3 times. Do you know why?